# Deployment keeps failing on Netlify when using netlify.toml

Tags: reactjs, express, nodemailer, netlify

I'm working on an SPA with React and I'm using Nodemailer with Express and Google APIs to send emails through a contact form at /contactos. Everything is working but the deployment process fails.

I have a `netlify.toml` file that looks like this:

```
[build]
   functions = "functions"
   command = "node functions/mailer.js && npm run build"
```

A folder called `functions` in which I have a file called `mailer.js` and I have all the code related to Nodemailer over there:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.post('/enviar', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.formData);
  const userInfo = req.body.formData;

  const EMAIL = process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL;
  const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID;
  const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
  const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI;
  const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN;

  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI
  );
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

  const sendMail = async () => {
    try {
      const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          type: 'OAuth2',
          user: EMAIL,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
          refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
          accessToken: accessToken,
        },
      });
      let mailOptions = {
        from: `${userInfo.firstName} ${userInfo.lastName} <${userInfo.email}>`,
        to: EMAIL,
        subject: `Correo enviado por ${userInfo.firstName} ${userInfo.lastName} desde el sitio web`,
        text: `${userInfo.message}`,
        html: `
              <p>¡Tienes un nuevo correo electrónico enviado desde el sitio web de LynStore!</p>
              <h3>Detalles del contacto:</h3>
              <ul>
                <li>Nombre: ${userInfo.firstName} ${userInfo.lastName}</li>
                <li>Correo: ${userInfo.email}</li>
              </ul>
              <h3>Mensaje:</h3>
              <p>${userInfo.message}</p>
              `,
      };
      const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error!!!!!!!', err);
    }
  };
  sendMail()
    .then((result) => res.json({ status: 'success' }))
    .catch((error) => {
      res.json({ status: 'fail' });
      console.log('Error en el envío!', error.message);
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

These are the last 27 lines of the deploy log on Netlify:

```
4:09:12 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:09:12 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
4:09:12 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ❯ Version
4:09:12 PM:   @netlify/build 26.0.2
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ❯ Flags
4:09:12 PM:   baseRelDir: true
4:09:12 PM:   buildId: 61c2425eebc157000771ab02
4:09:12 PM:   deployId: 61c2425eebc157000771ab04
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ❯ Current directory
4:09:12 PM:   /opt/build/repo
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ❯ Config file
4:09:12 PM:   /opt/build/repo/netlify.toml
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ❯ Context
4:09:12 PM:   production
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:09:12 PM:   1. build.command from netlify.toml                            
4:09:12 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:09:12 PM: ​
4:09:12 PM: $ node functions/mailer.js && npm run build
4:09:13 PM: Server is running on port: 3001
4:38:47 PM: Build exceeded maximum allowed runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Nelify functions don’t operate like a standard server, they have a runtime limit of 15 minutes, they are serverless and your code should be written in a way to support this rather than treating as a standard server deploy.

**A good express example is provided here**:

https://github.com/neverendingqs/netlify-express/blob/0780127cd575704e2a2a00a1a648ba5a5a66c388/express/server.js